# show and hide element in jquery with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I create survey poll in wordpress plugin to display questions i use ajax to display it

this is my html code

```
        <div id="my_poll">
            <button class="start" id="start"><b><?php _e('Start poll questions'); ?></b></button>
            <div id="poll" class="container mt-sm-5 my-1">
                <form>
                    <?php
                    if ($ques->have_posts()) {
                        while ($ques->have_posts()) {
                            $ques->the_post();
                            global $post;
                            $ID = $post->ID;
                            $option = get_post_meta($ID, "op1", true);
                            $nonce = wp_create_nonce("my_user_vote_nonce");
                            $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_user_vote&post_id=' . $ID . '&nonce=' . $nonce);
                            $ques_id = 'Q-' . $ID;
                    ?>
                            <div id="<?php echo $ques_id ?>" class="questions">
                                <div class="question ml-sm-5 pl-sm-5 pt-2">
                                    <h3><b><?php _e('Poll Survey'); ?></b></h3>

                                    <div class="py-2 h5"><b class="msg"><?php the_title() ?></b></div>
                                    <div class="ml-md-3 ml-sm-3 pl-md-5 pt-sm-0 pt-3" id="options">
                                        <label class="options"><?php _e($option['op1']['op1']); ?> <input type="radio" name="framework" value="<?php esc_attr_e($option['op1']['op1']) ?>"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label>
                                        <label class="options"><?php _e($option['op2']['op2']); ?> <input type="radio" name="framework" value="<?php esc_attr_e($option['op2']['op2']) ?>"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label>
                                        <label class="options"><?php _e($option['op3']['op3']); ?> <input type="radio" name="framework" value="<?php esc_attr_e($option['op3']['op3']) ?>"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-3">
                                        <div class="ml-auto mr-sm-5">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success">
                                                <?php
                                                echo '<a class="user_vote" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-post_id="' . $ID . '" href="' . $link . '">submit</a>';
                                                ?>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is my ajax to show and hide elements

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#poll").hide();
    var count = 0;

    jQuery(".start").click(function(e) {
        jQuery("#poll").show();
        jQuery(".start").hide();
    });

    jQuery(".user_vote").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        option = jQuery('input[name="framework"]:checked').val();
        post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id");
        nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce");

        var idArr = [];
        jQuery(".questions").each(function() {
            idArr.push(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "my_user_vote",
                post_id: post_id,
                nonce: nonce,
                option: option,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.type == "success") {
                    count++;
                    if (count < idArr.length) {
                        jQuery(".questions").hide();
                        jQuery("#" + idArr[count]).show();
                    } else {
                        jQuery("#my_poll").hide();
                        alert('Thank you for your time.')
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Your vote could not be added");
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

in this jquery ajax whene i click start button i display all questoins divs.

but i want display the first question div.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Your code looks overly complex. It's not clear what is not working or what you need help with.Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I recommend that; "use unique id values for each element in the page, and add id only if you need"

Answer (score 0):

Change the on click event function like below;

```
jQuery(".start").click(function(e) {
    jQuery(".start").hide();
    jQuery("#poll:first").show(); // id selector!
});
```

Better way, wirte "poll" word into the class attribute, dont use same id more than one time. If you change the id and class of the elements, your code must be like this;

```
jQuery(".start").click(function(e) {
    jQuery(".start").hide();
    jQuery(".poll:first").show(); // class selector
});
```

Also, you can use $ character instead of Jquery;

```
jQuery("div") EQUAL $("div")
```

Another way to find first element;

```
$(".start").click(function(e) {
    $(".start").hide();
    $(".poll").eq(0).show(); // class selector
});
```

Comment: it's not working